# Reference request: where is this text about abandoning hindrances from?

Tags: reference-request

I found the text below on another site. However, it doesn't say whether the source is a specific sutta, commentaries or something else. Could someone show me the origin?

> Six things are conducive to the abandonment of restlessness and remorse:
>
> 1. Knowledge of the Buddhist scriptures (Doctrine and Discipline);
> 2. Asking questions about them;
> 3. Familiarity with the Vinaya (the Code of Monastic Discipline, and for lay followers, with the principles of moral conduct);
> 4. Association with those mature in age and experience, who possess dignity, restraint and calm;
> 5. Noble friendship;
> 6. Suitable conversation.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Source: [Uddhacca,kukkucca](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/32.7-Uddhaccakukkucca-piya.pdf) by Piya Tan

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely taken from the commentary to the satipatthana sutta, which has a similar list for each of the five hindrances. They are all worth reading:

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/soma/wayof.html#hindrances